# JPA multi-entity relationship

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

How can I write the following relationship in JPA. I have 6 tables: Products, Features, Functions, Tasks, Permissions and Users.  I need to be able to create a Product object model that contains a list of Features.  Each Feature object model in the list will contain a list of Functions and each Function will contain a list of Tasks.  I have no issue building each one of these entities and then relating them together but the problem comes in when I need to filter each entity by its relationship to the Permission table.  I'm not sure this can be done.  When I map the Permissions entity to each other entity, I seem to get a many-to-many join and too many values are returned.  Any insight would be great.

```
Products
prod_id
user_id

Features
prod_id
feature_id

Functions
prod_id
feature_id
function_id

Tasks
prod_id
feature_id
function_id
task_id

Permissions
prod_id
feature_id
function_id
task_id
user_id

User
user_id
```

Here is my Permission entity class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@IdClass(menu.entity.PermissionKey.class)
@Entity
@Table(name="PERMISSIONS")
@NamedQuery(name = "findPermissionsByUserId",query = "SELECT p FROM Permission p WHERE p.userId = :userId")
public class Permission implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name="AUTH", length=1)
private String auth;

@Column(name="PERM_DESC", length=80)
private String permDesc;

@Id
@Column(name="COMPANY", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        length=2)
private String company;

@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID", 
        nullable = false, 
        insertable = false, 
        updatable = false,
        length=30)
private String userId;

@Id
@Column(name="PROD_ID", precision=22)
private BigDecimal prodId;

@Id
@Column(name="FEATURE", precision=22)
private BigDecimal feature;

@Id
@Column(name="FUNC", precision=22)
private BigDecimal func;

@Id
@Column(name="TASK", precision=22)
private BigDecimal task;

//uni-directional one-to-one association to Product
@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="permission")
private Product productObj;

@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="permission")
private Feature featureObj;

@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="permission")
private Function functionObj;

@OneToOne(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="permission")
private Task taskObj;

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY", referencedColumnName="COMPANY")
    })  
private User user;

public Permission() {
}

public String getAuth() {
    return this.auth;
}

public void setAuth(String auth) {
    this.auth = auth;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return this.company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public String getPermDesc() {
    return this.permDesc;
}

public void setPermDesc(String permDesc) {
    this.permDesc = permDesc;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public BigDecimal getProdId() {
    return prodId;
}

public void setProdId(BigDecimal prodId) {
    this.prodId = prodId;
}

public BigDecimal getFeature() {
    return this.feature;
}

public void setFeature(BigDecimal feature) {
    this.feature = feature;
}

public BigDecimal getFunc() {
    return func;
}

public void setFunc(BigDecimal func) {
    this.func = func;
}

public BigDecimal getTask() {
    return task;
}

public void setTask(BigDecimal task) {
    this.task = task;
}

public Product getProductObj() {
    return this.productObj;
}

public void setProductObj(Product productObj) {
    this.productObj = productObj;
}

public Feature getFeatureObj() {
    return this.featureObj;
}

public void setFeatureObj(Feature featureObj) {
    this.featureObj = featureObj;
}

public Function getFunctionObj() {
    return this.functionObj;
}

public void setFunctionObj(Function functionObj) {
    this.functionObj = functionObj;
}

public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Task getTaskObj() {
    return this.taskObj;
}

public void setTaskObj(Task taskObj) {
    this.taskObj = taskObj;
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you repeat the ID of every parent table in the child table? In tasks, you just need the function id. In functions, you just need the feature id. Avoid composite primary keys, and everything will be much easier, and much cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I agree that using composite primary keys makes the relationship difficult and perhaps a better model would be only primary key/foreign key relationship in each table but I still need to know how to filter the Product-Feature-Function-Task model by the Permissions table, while still returning a Products object with it's lower Feat, func and task objects.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is?  What error are you getting?  What do you mean by filter?  You mappings in Permission don't make sense, they should be using the join columns, not mappedBy, you have no foreign keys in the other tables.

Comment: My problem is that I need my User entity to relate to a Product(Feature, Function, Task) entity through the Permissions entity.  When I use the code above, it returns too many objects.  I'm working on changing the design of this to accommodate what I need.

Comment: Just to close this out.  I've come to the conclusion that it's not a logical relationship to join Permissions against Product in order to filter out Product,Feature,Function,Task.  What I did was bring back all Permissions and pass that into a HashMap in order to rebuild my tree structure.  Thanks everyone for your suggestions.